# How can I update com.android.support:exifinterface version

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-studio-2.3

Currently I am using Android Studio 2.3.3. I wanted to update the support library version from 25.3.1 to 26.0.1. So inside my build.gradle file I did all the necessery changes and changed all the support library versions from 25.3.1 to 26.0.1. After that when I synced the project it shows me an error(I have given a screenshot) in compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1 
**All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version...Found versions 26.0.1,25.3.1.Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1 and com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1**
[The error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozIDU.png)

**My question is that where can I find com.android.support:exifinterface to update**

I tried the same in Android Studio 3.0.0. That showed the same error

Comment: According to this page: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html it should be available in reop/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:~

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```